# how do I shorten the display name for an iPhone app in XCode 4, but leaving a longer product name that matches the App Name in iTunes Connect?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, app-store-connect

how do I shorten the display name for an iPhone app in XCode 4, but leaving a longer product name that matches the App Name in iTunes Connect?

(i.e. only issue I want to address here is the name under the app icon is a little long and needs to be contracted, but don't want to change the full name of the app in terms of how it will be advertised in the app store etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display name is determined by the Bundle Display Name property ([CFBundleDisplayName](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-110725-TPXREF135)) in the app's Info.plist.

Answer (score 1):

In your info.plist file just use different Values for the keys "Bundle Name" and "Display Bundle Name".

Answer (score 0):

1: The **CFBundleDisplayName** property in the .plist will determine the name that will be shown on the actual devices beneath the icons.
 2: You can set up the longer name shown on the App Store like this: log in to itunesconnect.com and go to "Manage Your Applications" and edit it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a note -- changing the bundle display name is the correct answer here, but you'll likely have to reset content and settings in your iOS simulator before you'll see the change actually take place. Confused me for a few minutes.